# Spring WebFlux Security + KeyCloak (oAuth) = unable to get user's permissions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

My goal is to authorise and authenticate User from Keycloak token using Spring Web Flux security.
As a result I wanna be able to access my microservice's secured endpoints based on User's role, which is parsed from the token.

**The problem is**: I can't pass controller's `PreAuthorize` security check using Keycloak's token because of `"o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthenticationWebFilter: Authentication failed: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"` error.

So I able to access the resources in my app while the token is valid, but since I secure my methods with `PreAuthorize`, it starts to give HTTP 401. I guess I missed smth in the config, so Authentication object is not being populated in my SecurityContext.

What am I missing?

Spring WebFlux Security main configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()  
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(keycloakJwtAuthConverter());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakJwtAuthConverter keycloakJwtAuthConverter() {
        return new KeycloakJwtAuthConverter();
    }
```

Converter from KeyCloak's JWT format.
Just placed a placeholder with predefined roles here for a while and checked that it's 100% being invoked in the debugger and produces the data.

```
public class KeycloakJwtAuthConverter
        implements Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> {

    @Override
    public Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken> convert(Jwt jwt) {

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        var newToken = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, "myuser");

        return Mono.just(newToken);
    }
}
```

Controller's code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Mono<String> greet(Mono<Principal> principal) {
        return principal
                .map(Principal::getName)
                .map(name -> String.format("Test, %s", name));
    }
}
```

Application.yaml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider: 
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:3000/realms/msapp
            user-name-attribute: name
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: msapp
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:3000/realms/msapp
          jwks-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have anything related to login in a resource server filter chain. Login is the responsibility of OAuth2 clients, not of resource servers. You might get some OAuth2 background from [my tutorials intro](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials).

To configure a reactive resource server with Role Based Access Control and **any** OpenID Provider (Keycloak included, of course), things can be very simple using ["my" starter](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/c4-soft/springaddons/spring-addons-starter-oidc/) in addition to official one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
scheme: http
origins: ${scheme}://localhost:4200
keycloak-port: 8442
keycloak-issuer: ${scheme}://localhost:${keycloak-port}/realms/master

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${keycloak-issuer}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - "/public/**"
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          cors:
          - path: /**
            allowed-origin-patterns: ${origins}

server:
  error:
    include-message: always
  ssl:
    enabled: false

---
scheme: https
keycloak-port: 8443

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: ssl
```

Comment: Thank you, I will remove excessive parts and will take a look at the code, you provided.

Comment: Above code does all the security config you need: configure a resource server `SecurityWebFilterChain` with disabled sessions and CSRF protection, a JwtAuthenticationConverter mapping authorities from the right claims, 401 for unauthorized requests, list of `permitAll` resources (what is not listed requires a valid authentication and access control is made with your annotations), and also CORS configuration if you need it. All that with just properties (and one dependency)

Answer (score 0):

I was need to use "@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity()" of Reactive stack.
Such inattention. Shame on me.